# diary-float query for Emacs Diary

Tags: emacs

In the Emacs manual the following is furnished as an example of a special entry in the Emacs Diary:

&%%(diary-float 11 4 4) American Thanksgiving

The 11 specifies the month, the first 4 specifies the day of the week (Thursday) and the second 4 the 4th Thursday of the month.

One can use t to indicate all months of the year, but how would one specify all Thursdays of the month? I have tried t and it does not work.

For example, let's say that every October I have to perform a duty, but not every day, only every Thursday. How would I capture that using a diary-float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with `diary-float`, but as described in [Sexp Entries](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sexp-Diary-Entries.html) in the Emacs manual, you can use an arbitrary Lisp expression in the diary file.  This seems to work:

```
%%(let ((dayname (calendar-day-of-week date))
        (month (car date)))
    (and (= month 10) (= dayname 4))) It's a Thursday in October
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I required.

Comment: You're welcome! If you found the answer useful, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it.